# android - object animation - how to make animations play sequentially instead of all at once

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am animating a demonstration of the bubble sort. When the button is clicked, it is supposed to:

- Output 10 bars in order of length - this is done with `ImageViews` in the `XML`.
- Create an `ArrayList` with the integers from 1 to 10 in it, and then shuffle it using `Collections.shuffle()`
- Shuffle the bars using object animation on the screen.
- While running a bubble sort, show each swap by swapping two bars in the interface.

When I run the app, it doesn't show each swap but instead seems to play everything all at once, including all the swaps and even the shuffle and the swapping together. They all end up sorted, but it isn't a visual demonstration. Here is the java below (lots of unnecessary libraries imported from earlier experimentation) : `
    package com.propertyanimationtester;

```
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.lang.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public void startAnimation(View view) {

    ImageView[] bars = new ImageView[10];

    ImageView bar1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar1));
    ImageView bar2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar2));
    ImageView bar3 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar3));
    ImageView bar4 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar4));
    ImageView bar5 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar5));
    ImageView bar6 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar6));
    ImageView bar7 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar7));
    ImageView bar8 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar8));
    ImageView bar9 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar9));
    ImageView bar10 = (ImageView) this.findViewById((R.id.bar10));

    bars[0] = bar1;
    bars[1] = bar2;
    bars[2] = bar3;
    bars[3] = bar4;
    bars[4] = bar5;
    bars[5] = bar6;
    bars[6] = bar7;
    bars[7] = bar8;
    bars[8] = bar9;
    bars[9] = bar10;

    ArrayList<Integer> lengthslist = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);

    for (int lengthsfiller = 0; lengthsfiller < 10; lengthsfiller++) {
        lengthslist.add(lengthsfiller);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(lengthslist);

    for (int shuffleReplacement = 0; shuffleReplacement < 10; shuffleReplacement++) {
        MoveBar(view, bars[shuffleReplacement], shuffleReplacement, lengthslist.get(shuffleReplacement));
    }

    bubbleSort(lengthslist, view, bars);
}

public void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> list, View view, ImageView[] bars)
{
    for(int outerloop=0; outerloop<10; outerloop++)
    {
        for(int innerloop=0; innerloop < 9; innerloop++)
        {
            if(list.get(innerloop) > list.get(innerloop+1))
            {


                SwapBars(view, bars[list.get(innerloop)], bars[list.get(innerloop+1)], innerloop, innerloop + 1);


                Collections.swap(list, innerloop, innerloop + 1);

            }
        }

    }
}

public void MoveBar(View view, View bar, int currentArrayPosition, int newArrayPosition) {
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar,"y", (20.0f + 30.0f*(currentArrayPosition)) * scale, (20.0f+ 30.0f*(newArrayPosition)) * scale);

    AnimatorSet moveSingleBarAnimSet = new AnimatorSet();

    moveSingleBarAnimSet.play(animation);

    moveSingleBarAnimSet.setDuration(1000);
    moveSingleBarAnimSet.setInterpolator(new  AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    moveSingleBarAnimSet.start();


}

public void SwapBars(View view, ImageView bar1, ImageView bar2, int position1, int position2) {
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar1,"x", 20.0f * scale, 220.0f * scale);
    ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar1,"y", (20.0f + 30.0f* position1) * scale, (20.0f + 30.0f * position2) * scale);
    ObjectAnimator anim3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar1,"x", 220.0f * scale, 20.0f * scale);

    ObjectAnimator anim4 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar2,"x", 20.0f * scale, 220.0f * scale);
    ObjectAnimator anim5 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar2,"y", (20.0f + 30.0f * position2) * scale, (20.0f + 30.0f * position1) * scale);
    ObjectAnimator anim6 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar2,"x", 220.0f * scale, 20.0f * scale);

    AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();


    animSet.play(anim1).before(anim2).before(anim5).with(anim4);
    animSet.play(anim2).before(anim3).before(anim6).with(anim5);
    animSet.play(anim3).with(anim6);


    animSet.setDuration(1000);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animSet.start();
}
```

}
`

And the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar2"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar1"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/bar3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar2"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/bar4"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar3"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/bar5"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar4"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar6"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar5"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar7"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar6"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar8"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar7"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar9"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar8"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar10"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar9"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
    android:onClick="startAnimation"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

How am I able to stop all the animations from playing all at once? It matters less so for the `MoveBars` procedure, but definitely needs to show separate swaps for the `SwapBars` procedure. Any help would be really appreciated :)

Edit after question answered:

Used animSet.setStartDelay(time in Milliseconds)

Comment: Thats too much of code to gulp. You can try using a thread which delays your animations, one after the other?

Comment: You can use AnimationListener to notify when previous anymation has ended and only then trigger next.

Comment: Sorry about that, yeah I tried using threads but it delays the UI and all the swaps, I'm currently looking at ways around it doing that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a different delay for each animation by setting [setStartDelay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) for each ObjectAnimator you create.